# Counting primitive operations

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, primitive, asymptotic-complexity

Here are the primitive operations I am considering:

- Assigning a value to a variable
- Calling a method
- Performing an arithmetic operation
- Comparing two numbers
- Following an object reference

I have a good understanding of how to count them for a normal for loop like so:

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) { ... }
```

This would be 4 + n + n * (number of primitive operations in the for-loop body), because we have:

- 1 for initializing i as 1
- n + 1 for comparing i to n
- 2 for i++ since this is just i = i + 1 which is both an assign and addition
- And then we repeat the body n times, hence we multiply the body by n

However, I'm stuck on how to count this:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i+2) { ... }
```

For comparisons, I'm thinking this is `1+ceil(n/2)`, but how do I get rid of the ceil function?

For repeats of the body, I'm thinking `floor((n+1)/2)`, but I'm unsure how to get rid of the floor function.

Comment: You can just approximate with n/2 and (n+1)/2 for all purposes of calculating asymptotic complexity and O(n)

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of these functions? They accurately describe your operation count.

Comment: I'm being asked to give the a count of primitive operations. This for loop is just one small section of a much larger, more complex method. If I didn't have the functions, I'd be able to multiply everything out, and simplify to a simple equation.

Comment: You can't easily. You can rewrite the expression with modulus

Comment: If you are asked co calculate the exact number of operations, you have to work with these functions. You probably should try to clarify your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
Algorithm prefixAvg2(X):
  input: An n-element array X
  output: An n-element array A of numbers such that A[i] is the average of elements X[0], ..., X[i]

1 Declare and initialize array A
2 a = 0
3 for i = 0 to n-1 do
4   a += X[i]
5   A[i] = a / (i+1)
6 return array A
```